# SQLite for iPhone issues/bugs/problems?

Tags: iphone, debugging, sqlite

I am planning to develop an iPhone application heavily relying on sqlite DB , 
from different links I have gone through this seems to be a great tool and has some really good support.

As my app is still in the planning process

**I would like to ask if there are any Issues with SQLlite database ? from memory management to Queries and data sizes and multiple access etc;**

Please share your experience using SQLite DB in iPhone and what problems did you face?

I just want to make a note of these exceptions so that I may plan my App well and do not have any issues raised in the middle of the development process.

Thanx for your contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not looking to support the OS version 2.x or below I would (as the apple and may be the other developers) suggest to use the core-data. Its a lot simpler and easy to handle than sqlite. See the [apple support](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/01_StartingOut.html) and this [sample](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) for more help.

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion. Can I use core data to sync my app with an online DB ?

Comment: @jAmi this link might be helpful to you http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/46187-core-data-syncing-database-web.html